# Video is uploaded as an image from iOS device, how to upload properly

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I have an app that gets the images/videos from the mobile gallery, then uploads one of them to a server,
here are the steps i take, which works fine on Android:

**1-get data from mobile storage:**

```
MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
  first: 20,
  mediaType: [MediaLibrary.MediaType.video, MediaLibrary.MediaType.photo]
})
```

**2-upload to server:**

```
formData.append('images[]', {
    uri: localUri,  
    name: isVideo ? 'untitled.mp4'  : 'untitled',//for testing
    type: isVideo ? 'video/mp4' : 'image/jpeg'
})

axios.post(`url`, formData, {headers: headers,timeout:999999})
```

The problem is videos are uploaded as an image (only the first frame of the video), while it gets uploaded successfully on Android, the problem is only present on iOS.

The uri of the retrieved files is as follows:
`assets-library://asset/asset.MP4?id=xxx&ext=MP4`

**Quick notes:**

1 - the video is played fine locally using the `<Video>` component from Expo

2 - i tried using the `CameraRoll` API, but it gives the same results, and is a little buggy

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can update to expo SDK 36 and you will be able to solve this problem by using `localUri` returned by `MediaLibrary.getAssetInfoAsync`

ex.

```
// get asset id like B84E8479-475C-4727-A4A4-B77AA9980897/L0/001
const info = await MediaLibrary.getAssetInfoAsync(asset.id)
const uri = info.localUri // use this for upload
```

Reffer this comment on github.
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/3177#issuecomment-510096711

Comment: I was facing the same problem with expo SDK 40 and this solved my problem. Thanks!